# Can a website Demand acceptance of non-essential cookies to allow free access?

Tags: european-union, cookies

I have experienced several times now that sites require payment if you do not accept non-essential cookies. My reading of the relevant legislation (from the EU - I have not browsed the Californian legilation) indicates that I, as a consumer, should be allowed to refuse cookies that I do not want to accept.

Is it legal for them to block access and require payment? (I am not blocking ads - just saying that they cannot target ads to me. I cannot comprehend how me not allowing them to save a cookie would make them try to block my access)

Just to clarify: I am aware that collection of demographic data can be important to ensure that your content and ad campaigns are relevant to visitors. My concern however is that I don't see how I have to accept to be tracked more than strictly necessary to read their site - this is cookies, not blocking ads!

The types of sites have always been news sites.

I have read [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/85524/is-consent-required-for-paying-corporate-subscribers-of-a-b2b-website) answer and I don't feel that it has sufficiently answered the question I have.

Comment: What type of websites are you talking about?

Comment: @JoeW These are quite common "news" websites (often infested with click-bait-articles, though but that's irrelevant here): When you open the website, you are asked to either allow all cookies _or_ pay to visit the site ad-free. There's no "visit with ads, but don't track me" button.

Comment: I don't know whether what they do is legal, but as a workaround, I'm only visiting such pages with my browser in "private" mode.

Comment: @PMF I would say it is relevant in the fact that those types of sites do a lot of shady things many of which are not likely within the rules and regulations.

Comment: One has to remember that without cookies, they will basically have no advertising revenue. Advertisers either explicitly only pay per sale (CPA) rather than per display (CPM) or per click (CPC), or if they do pay CPM or CPC, if there is no match between the origin of the traffic and the sales it generates, they will consider that source of traffic to not be worth the cost and drop it.

Comment: @jcaron not true - without cookies thay cannot target ads to me specifically, but if the ads are aligned with the subject matter of the article (which I MUST be interested in - I clicked the link) they still have a chance of getting a hit. I generally have the theory that the more you advertise for somehting, the worse the product must be (my best example is McDonalds ;-) ) I get sceptical if I see too many ads for something

Comment: @JoSSte I'm not saying you won't generate revenue for the advertiser, I'm saying it won't be possible (or more difficult or limited, especially if you don't buy right away, but on a subsequent visit, and/or if you also refuse cookies on that advertiser's site) to match that revenue with the fact that you came from that site.

Comment: @jcaron 99% of those ads have URL parameters set so that the sending site can be identified, so I am not in complete agreement with that site.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your title is not necessarily consistent with your example.

> Can a website demand acceptance of non-essential cookies to allow access?

As you have found, GDPR prohibits conditioning the provision of service on consent to the processing of personal data. Cookie walls *without alternative means of access* are generally considered violations of the GDPR.

> Can a website demand acceptance of non-essential cookies to allow *free* access?

The situation of a "consent or pay" scheme (or "cookie paywalls") is more uncertain and has not been clearly settled at the EU level. There are data protection authorities that do not consider such scheme necessarily a GDPR violation ([Austria](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/JudikaturEntscheidung.wxe?Abfrage=Dsk&Dokumentnummer=DSBT_20181130_DSB_D122_931_0003_DSB_2018_00&ShowPrintPreview=True), [France](https://www.cnil.fr/fr/cookies-et-autres-traceurs/regles/cookie-walls/la-cnil-publie-des-premiers-criteres-devaluation)) if a reasonable alternative access, without requiring non-essential cookies, is provided. For what it is worth, the French data protection authority (CNIL) held initially that all cookie walls are illegal, but on appeal from publishers and advertisers, the French supreme administrative court annulled CNIL's initial guidelines for being too absolute.

German and Italian authorities are still examining the validity of such scheme.

More reading:

- Consent or Pay: Privacy Considerations with Cookiewall-Paywall Hybrid Solution, https://securiti.ai/blog/cookie-paywall/
- Is the use of a cookie wall allowed in European Countries, https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/24487-cookie-walls-gdpr

Comment: I thought that the GDPR was a later legislation than the cookie legislation. I do see that they are related, and that the cookie legislation has been tightened as a result of GDPR though.